# What happens if you push and pull 5 balls simultaneously connected by springs at opposite ends?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring, elasticity

Say you have 5 balls connected by Steel springs in space .
Each ball is 1 KG
Distance between each ball is 1 Meter.
Total Object is 5 Meters

1--2--3--4--5

say you push 1 and pull 5 simultaneously with 100 Newtons

Push 100N ~> 1~-2--3--4-~5~> 100N Pull

What happens to ball 3 when the energy/longitude waves meets ?

Does the ball move towards 5?

IF it move towards 5 what would the exact force in that moment of time be?

or does it not move?

IF it does not move then what happens to the momentum?

How would you go about solving this, Specifically what formulas/equations would I need?
I've started with Hookes Law but am confused on determine a spring constant in this situation as its in space with no gravity.

My goal is to mimic something actually calculatable in terms of the restoring force in material due to electromagnetic forces.

To ask my question elegantly what happens at the exact moment when the two longitude waves meet at Ball 3?

Comment: The spring constant is a property of the spring itself;  it doesn't rely on gravity for its definition.  A spring is "springy" even in zero-G, and if you compress/stretch it by a length $x$ then it will exert a force of magnitude $kx$ on each of its ends.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert . Correct , but how do you calculate a spring constant without weight could you just make up one ?

Comment: You got a lot of useful information [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskPhysics/comments/v0v5te/what_happens_if_you_push_and_pull_5_balls/). Have you applied those formulas in a simpler example to start building up a solution, as recommended?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: More or less, yes.  A better way to think about it is that the springs have a spring constant $k$, the masses have a mass $m$, and the applied forces have magnitude $F$ — in other words, use symbols rather than numbers to do the derivation, and proceed as far as you can without using numbers.  That way you'll have more flexibility to see how your results depend on the amount of force, the spring stiffness, and the other properties of the system.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://www.falstad.com/loadedstring/ Set the number of loads to 5. Set the Stopped checkbox to arrange an initial condition with the Mouse.

Answer (score 0):

You would set up Newton's Second Law for each of the five masses.  If the initial positions of each of the five masses are $x_i = 0$, and the springs are initially at their equilibrium lengths, then the force exerted by each spring will be of magnitude $k(x_i - x_{i+1})$.

Newton's Second law for each of the masses would be
\begin{align*}
m \ddot{x}_1 &= F_\text{app} - k (x_1 - x_2) \\
m \ddot{x}_2 &= -k(x_2 - x_1) - k (x_2 - x_3) \\
& \vdots \\
m \ddot{x}_5 &= F_\text{app} - k(x_5 - x_4) \\
\end{align*}

You would then need to solve these differential equations given the initial conditions $x_i(0) = \dot{x}_i(0) = 0$.  While it is possible to do this by hand, use of a computer (either to solve the problem numerically or exactly) would be a great help.  Once you have this solution, you can figure out the position, velocity, and acceleration of any mass at any particular time.

Comment: Copy, guess I have to learn how to solve differential equations , how hard is a problem like this ?

Comment: @SebastianColon: It is not a beginner's problem, to be sure.  But knowing how to tackle a system of ODEs (either numerically or analytically) is a valuable skill. If you already know how to code in a particular language, try searching "numerical differential equations [language]" and see what comes up.  (The exact analytical techniques for this kind of problem are much more complicated.)

Comment: What is the double dot over X ?

Comment: @SebastianColon:  That means "the second time derivative of $x$".  If you ever encounter $\dot{x}$ in your reading, that means "the first time derivative of $x$".

Comment: Analyzing this equation with my friend is this taking into account both forces from the separate sides ?

Comment: @SebastianColon:  Yes.  As you can see, the applied forces only appear in the acceleration equations for $x_1$ and $x_5$.